# How do I set the license for images on my site in Google Images?

Tags: microformats, google-image-search

Google Images has an option to filter images based on license.

[image: License filter screenshot]

Each image on my site has a details page, where I have the following link to denote the license:

`<a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.en_US" target="_blank">CC-BY</a>`

It's a modified version of the sample code from [Creative Commons - Choose a License](http://creativecommons.org/choose/).

However, I see images that Google has indexed since I added this code do not appear when I select a license filter.

Comment: Check out this post http://codegena.com/label-image-license-types-for-google-images/

Comment: Done. It has the same info in the answer posted here a year ago, and it was written by you.

Comment: Yes, but atleast I have written a little more. I found the answer from google's blog and not from the answer. Anyway thanks for checking it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap it around a div with an about attribute. Here's an example that Google provides:

```
<div about="image.jpg">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
  <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike 3.0</a>
</div>
```

So in your case:

```
<div about="image.jpg">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
  <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.en_US" target="_blank">CC-BY</a>
</div>
```

Sources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quyhasVn2jw, http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/08/simple-way-to-specify-image-licenses.html

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I'm going to implement it and make sure it works before I accept.