# markdown: How to add a link to markdown image title

Tags: markdown, hexo

I am using Hexo and want to use several images from Wikipedia Commons in my post. Thus I'd like to add the license when I use it.

I choose inline style to use it:

`![image title](image.exmaple.com)`

However, when I try to add the license link to the title, it doesn't work:

`![image title [license name][license.example.com]](image.example.com)`

So I wonder how could I add the link of license to image title or if there are any other ways to add license link gracefully. Thanks!

Comment: As Markdown is a subset of HTML, you might want to explore [how to do this with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3032828/866026). My guess is you will need to revert to raw HTML in your Markdown document.

Comment: If you still need help, then I would suggest editing your question to include the HTML output you would like to get. Perhaps we can then provide the Markdown required to generate that HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Waylan. I think you are right. As Markdown is the subset of HTML and the value of img alt is text, it's reasonable that I cannot add a link to it. And I find this HTML code works for me: [How do I set the license for images on my site in Google Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656219/how-do-i-set-the-license-for-images-on-my-site-in-google-images).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need. If you want to add licenses, for example.

```
[![Open Source Love](https://badges.frapsoft.com/os/v1/open-source.svg?v=103)](https://github.com/ellerbrock/open-source-badge/)
```

will generate a licenses like this 
[image: Open Source Love]